# How can I debug a newly cloned React Native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, debugging, expo

I am starting to help someone with a new project. This project is React (React Native as is a mobile app).

The project is working fine on her laptop (in her browser), and when I scan the Expo QR code, the app works fine on my Android device.

However, trying to run it in my browser is throwing all these errors:

[image]

The 'Can't resolve' error doesn't make sense, because the correct react native files are there. Is this a cache problem? I have tried deleting the .expo/web/cache folder and starting over.

Also, why are there multiple errors in my console, but only one being shown in the information on the actual web page? Does this mean that the single error being shown is causing all the other errors, or it is the only one which needs fixing, or will it show the next error when I fix the one that is being shown?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have been a known problem re babel. See the links below:

https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/173

[how to solve this error You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48034538/how-to-solve-this-error-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-t)